# Recover javascript logs and errors on Internet Explorer without F12 tool

Tags: javascript, windows, internet-explorer, logging, console.log

The main idea is to run a random page on Internet Explorer and get javascript errors and logs.

> Is there a way to recover javascript console logs and execution error
>   from a random web page without accessing the F12 tool on Internet
>   Explorer?

---

I found that with Chrome based browser, you can get it on your AppData file log by adding `--enable-logging --v=1` args when launching.

**Any solution with any language** are welcome.

Thank you for your answer.

NOTE :

`random page` on Internet Explorer means that I do not have the access on the source code.

Comment: you can define your own console.log() to collect the calls, what you do with it from there is needs-dependent.

Answer (score 1):

Basic solution to this would be:
1. Use Exception Handling to catch the errors.
2. Log errors in a Global Array
3. Log the errors in a file using Blob and URL.createObjectURL. All recent browsers support this.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a Bookmarklet that:

1. Overrides window.console.log and window.console.error (to intercept messages)
2. Logs incoming messages somewhere using createObjectURL?

Or you could use something like firebuglite and auto-enable it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite.js">
{
    overrideConsole: false,
    startInNewWindow: true,
    startOpened: true,
    enableTrace: true
}
</script>
```

More instructions are here: http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite

Answer (score 1):

If the F12 tool is not of your interest, then what about the Event Viewer? Open Event Viewer from Control Panel -> System and Security -> Administrative Tools -> Event Viewer.‌ Then select the log Applications and Services Logs\Internet Explorer.

By default no events are being logged for Internet Explorer, to enable them create a new DWORD registry value named Feature_Enable_Compat_Logging under the following registry key:

```
HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Internet Explorer\Main \FeatureControl
```

and set the registry value to 1.

Check the logs you get to see if it's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

One idea would be to write a browser extension which listens for `window.onerror` and writes to a file.  Definitely not as elegant as the Chrome solution, but it would work fairly well.

Answer (score 0):

Using local proxy might be a good one-time solution.
`Charles` web debugging proxy app has nice UI and it allows to replace any response with local resource.

So basically you'll need:

1. Download one any of the js files used on target page
2. add any code you wish to saved version
3. set up `Charles` to serve you your local version instead of remote one

Answer (score 0):

You might try Fiddler. It's got its own logging and has amazing inspection power. It won't capture IE specific errors, since it's at a different layer, but it will definitely get you any code that's coming over the wire.